# Identify The People A User Follows In TableView Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing a search for users in my app that shows all users and displays a follow button next to each user. If the current, signed in user already follows the user in the cell, I want to change the display and text of the button in the cell. I found an extremely inefficient solution that I assume will cause major issues at scale which is every time I build a cell to loop through the current user's followers and see if the cell's `userid` matches one of the `userids` in the followers. This is what that code looked like in my `configureCell()` function.

```
let currentUserFollowers = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("follows")


    currentUserFollowers.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               self.follows = []
               if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                   for snap in snapshot {
                    print("SNAP USER - \(snap.key)")
                    if snap.key == user.userUid {
                        self.followButton.backgroundColor = .green
                        self.followButton.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
                    }
                   }
               }

           })
```

I don't think this is a great long term solution. So, my other thought was to run this function elsewhere and build an array of the `userids` the current user follows. The issue with here was that the cells were built before the asynchronous call to Firebase was finished building the array so I didn't have access to those values in the array.

```
func getCurrentUserFollowers () {

    let currentUserFollowers = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("follows")


    currentUserFollowers.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               self.follows = []
               if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                   for snap in snapshot {
                    print("SNAP USER - \(snap.key)")
                    self.follows.append(snap.key)
                    print("SELF FOLLOWS - \(self.follows)")
                       //let postData = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(snap.key)
                       /*postData.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                           if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                               let key = snapshot.key
                               let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                               //self.posts.append(post)
                           }
                           //self.feedTableView.reloadData()
                       })*/
                   }
               }

           })
}
```

And called it here:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    getCurrentUserFollowers()
    //isFollowing = false
    // Initialization code
}
```

I think the right approach is to build the array once and then use it when I configure my cells. Is that the best approach? If so, how can I have the array populated before `configureCell()` begins? The structure of the data is as follows:

```
  "users" : {
    "0hyN8N2klJWqPi2lkRqNK3vg7z63" : {
      "followers" : {
        "26OUuaRZEVWUmkLJp13LzirGbs13" : true,
        "gQpktBMh97hTqiysHBwvVLZl70y1" : true
      },
      "follows" : {
        "26OUuaRZEVWUmkLJp13LzirGbs13" : true,
        "gQpktBMh97hTqiysHBwvVLZl70y1" : true
      },
      "posts" : {
        "-Ly6ciYHm7v5JFy1VmVY" : true,
        "-Ly6cyLukI6aRRki5yna" : true
      },
      "provider" : "Firebase"
    }
```

EDIT: As @Jay pointed out below, I need to build the array and then pass to the VC that manages the tableview. I am thinking I need something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
    let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers![3] as! SearchUsersViewController
    destinationViewController.follows = follows
}

func observeUsersFollowed() {
    print("FOLLOWS ARRAY - \(follows)")
    let currentUserFollowers = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("follows")


    currentUserFollowers.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               self.follows = []
               if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                   for snap in snapshot {
                    print("SNAP USER - \(snap.key)")
                    if snap.key == self.user.userUid {
                        self.follows.append(self.user.userUid)
                    }
                   }
               }

           })

}
```

Comment: Without delving to deeply into your code, my suggestion is to read in the uid's of the users this user follows into an array. That would be a couple hundred so low memory impact. Then, as you are displaying the list of all users (probably using pagination), compare each of users uid with the one stored in the array and if it matches, mark that cell accordingly. That should be a pretty straight forward approach.

Comment: @Jay I like that idea. I am having a hard time thinking about how to implement it. Would you read in and fill array with the uids on the main page of the app then pass that array to the custom cell? If so, how is that done? How can my custom cell access that array from the main page VC?

Comment: At a high level, when the user authenticates read in their node and the uid's of who they follow - store that in an array. At some point thereafter, you're going to populate a dataSource (that backs your tableView) with users. Then in `tableView: cellForRowAt` compare the user that's going into the cell being constructed; see if that users uid is in the array and if so, update the button in that cell indicating they are already being followed.

Comment: @Jay How do I access that array from the VC of the tableview if the these are separate tabs in a tab bar? I have passed data with prepare for segue in the past but can't figure out how to do this in the case of tabs.

Comment: @Jay I made an edit with what I'm thinking based on your comment.

Comment: If you're using tabs you may be using a 'parent' TabViewController? If so, you can just store the array in that viewController and all the child views would have access to it. That would avoid passing completely as it would be one central location for the data. Also this code `currentUserFollowers.observe(.value` may become an issue because with every change within currenetUserFollowers (add, change or remove) the **entire list** is reloaded. You probably want a more granular approach with .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the advice of @Jay, I built an array in the parent tab and then accessed that array from my `SearchUsersViewController` with the following:

```
let tbvc = self.tabBarController  as! CustomTabBarController
follows = tbvc.follows

    for person in follows {
        //Check if the person in the followers array matches the current row
        if person == users[indexPath.row].userUid {
            print("PERSON - \(person) USER - \(users[indexPath.row].userUid)")
            isFollowing = true
        }
    }
```

And I passed the `isFollowing` variable to my `configureCell` function.